# How allow HTMLField in Django Admin and reflect that on the template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django app with this model:

```
class Dorm(models.Model):
    dorm_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter dorm name")
    dorm_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter dorm description")
```

This model has been added to the Django Admin:

```
class DormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('dorm_name','dorm_room_count','dorm_caretaker','dorm_contact_no','dorm_availability')
    list_filter = ('dorm_room_count','dorm_caretaker','dorm_availability','dorm_date_added')

    fieldsets = (
       (None, {'fields': ('dorm_name', 'dorm_description', 'dorm_primary_picture', 'dorm_room_count')}),
       ('Contact Details', {'fields': ('dorm_address','dorm_caretaker','dorm_contact_no','dorm_contact_email')}),
       ('Date',{'fields': ('dorm_date_added','dorm_availability','dorm_date_updated')}),
       ('Others',{'fields': ('dorm_house_rules',)}),
    )
```

I pulled that dorm_description using this in the template:

```
<div class="amenities">
    <div class="titlediv">About this dorm</div>
    <h5 class="padding-bottom">{{ dorm.dorm_description }}</h5>
</div>
```

However, in the template it is not displaying the line breaks as I have done in the Django Admin. It is wrapping everything up and ignoring the linebreaks. Can anyone help?

Here are the screenshots:

Django App Display: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSsdm.png)

Django Admin Display: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyxma.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `<br>` html tag to your text and render text field as plain html using [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter:

```
<h5 class="padding-bottom">{{ dorm.dorm_description|safe }}</h5>
```

Note that in this case non-admin users shouldn't have access to modify `dorm_description` to prevent [xss attack](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection).

Comment: You are right. It worked. Thanks. But I am worried on the XSS attack possibility. Right now, I am planning on keeping this question open for awhile until someone provides a different solution.

Comment: @django_python_newbie, to prevent XSS, you can use HTML sanitizing library, such as [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach). You define allowed tags that are non-problematic from XSS point of view and clean the rest with `bleach.clean(<posted_dorm_description>, tags=['strong', 'b', 'br', 'h1' etc.])`. `tags` is a list of allowed tags.